# Unit root test on growth variable?

Tags: unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

When constructing an ADF unit root test, is it Ok that input data is a growth variable? I was thinking about when you compute growth rate $\left(\frac{Y_t - Y_{t-1}}{Y_{t-1}}\right)$ and when differencing that's the expression above the line ($Y_t - Y_{t-1}$)..

Comment: It is OK, but most growth rates in economics or finance will not have unit roots, so you know what to expect.

Comment: ok thanks, I was scared I "cheated" to not get I(2) for my variables